# Gmap : retrieve marker inside direction?

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I try to find how to get marker inside direction that user point in Google map

Suppose that User start at point A to point B
and inside my Database has marker of Shopping store
how could we know that Shopping store is in direction from A to B or not
if yes then show marker of store on the map

Any suggestion to do that, Thank you

Comment: so, you are attempting to use the google direction to see if your marker of shopping store is within route of the direction that is rendered?

Answer (score 0):

Gettings locations that are en route will be hard. A better way might be to use some math to get the point that is in the middle of the 2 locations. Use that point and use the haversine formula to select locations from your table that are 1/2 the distance of the entire trip away from that point. This will get you points close to the route.